# What should be done when there is an incorrect common answer that keeps getting deleted when the answerer realizes their mistake?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

For a mild example of what I'm talking about, see [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94815/unearthed-arcana-does-warlock-invocation-kiss-of-mephistopheles-require-you-to) 5e question.

There have now been three answers (two deleted, one (currently) undeleted) pointing out that by 5th level, a Fiend patron warlock would have Fireball on their patron's Expanded Spells list and, therefore, there is no scenario in which they can have that invocation but not know fireball. This answer is incorrect, as unlike most other similar expanded spell list features (likely the common cause of confusion), warlocks do not automatically know the spells on their expanded list and therefore do not automatically know Fireball.

What should be done in scenarios like this where there's a common misunderstanding causing people to give an incorrect answer that they delete after realizing, which leads to another person with the same misunderstanding doing the same thing because they don't see the corrected mistake of the previous answerer?

[In the past](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92652/how-do-long-rests-work-for-small-parties#comment212918_92652) when dealing with common mistakes that pop up in several answers, I've left a comment on the question in hopes that answerers notice before answering, but I have no idea if that's the proper method of handling this vs. simply continuing to correct the most recent 'wrong' answer in comments when it pops up again.

Answer (score 21):

Put a comment on the question, submit an edit with that note in the question, or submit an answer that says "while it's a common misconception that..."

Comment: An advanced option is to ask and answer a question about the misconception, and add a link to it as a comment on the question.

Comment: An even *more* advanced option is to get your question and answer about the misconception into the official errata for the game, then get SevenSidedDie to cite it on meta.rpg.se.

Comment: And the *most* advanced option is to simply be hired by WotC, work you way up through positions until you're in a prime position to unleash a **Sneak Attack** on Jeremy Crawford, at which point you use your **Disguise Kit** to replace him and write the official rules yourself.

Answer (score 4):

#### It may be okay to leave one of the answers up with a pile of downvotes.

[This is what has happened](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/94914/62294) on the linked question. A substantial negative score is a great sign post that says "this answer is wrong", and in this case, the answer also has a helpful explanatory comment detailing why the answer is wrong.

In this situation, it is probably just fine, *because the author is inactive*:

> Last seen Nov 3 '17 at 23:37

Obviously, an active user is free to delete their wrong posts if they want. But in this case, the community has to decide to delete the answer, and it seems to be serving its purpose of sign posting that the repeated wrong answer is wrong.

Comment: And it has 2 Delete votes

Comment: @KorvinStarmast We can fix that! Let's delete it then undelete it.