# Who moderates the moderators?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

Why do moderators ban people from posting the truth? Are false notions more valuable than integrity? Every time I try to correct a false answer with a direct quote from the book, I am deleted by the moderator who posted the false answer. Why cant he just be a man, admit he is wrong and apologize for answering before he knew what he was talking about?

Chain of events spans 2013 and 2018:

- [How do vulnerabilities combine, when taking multiple types of damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/how-do-vulnerabilities-combine-when-taking-multiple-types-of-damage/25649#25649) Answered in 2013
- [How does Resist work against 1 attack that deals 2 separate damage types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25650/how-does-resist-work-against-1-attack-that-deals-2-separate-damage-types) Asked in 2013, closed as a dupe of the previous question
- [How does resist all apply to an attack that deals two types of (non-combined) damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25739/how-does-resist-all-apply-to-an-attack-that-deals-two-types-of-non-combined-da) Answered in 2018 with a new account, deleted for low quality & having no rules backing, later revised after deletion
- Reposted and self-answered in 2018 in [Damage resistance vs added damage by the RAW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127430/damage-resistance-vs-added-damage-by-the-raw), which was closed as a duplicate of the previous question, along with another non-answer on this question which was deleted.
- Posted https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127438/who-moderates-the-moderators which was moved here.

Comment: How do you know who deleted your question? Do your answers use good formatting and sentence structure?

Comment: @lucasvw bad formatting and such is hardly a reason for deletion, at least not without effort to explain or edit.

Comment: Could you provide examples of any kind?

Comment: @J.E true but I'm trying to glean more info from OP. Right now it's pretty vague.

Comment: This question does not seem to be asked in good faith... while I think the situation is worth looking into, I don't think the current wording is going to help with that.

Comment: Probably the post in question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127430/38502

Comment: *Every time I try to correct a false answer with a direct quote from the book, I am deleted by the moderator who posted the false answer* — please provide at least one specific example.

Comment: Gosh, I'm really tempted to VtC as unclear until OP points us to examples. It can't be the job of readers to read someone's complaint, poke around in that user's history to try and divine what they *might* be talking about, and then address their assumptions about OP's displeasure. Yeah, I've talked myself into it. Experienced users: ping me if you think this is in error, please.

Comment: Chaz II: if this complaint stems from a particular action or cluster of tightly-related actions (one or two questions in a day, for instance) please link to and describe what happened, as others have asked. If this concerns a large pattern you feel is at play please link to many examples. Either way, [edit] to make it clear to readers what you're actually talking about, then go ahead and flag this for reopening. Thanks.

Comment: @enkryptor I think Chaz is under the impression that I'm a moderator, simply because I've voted to delete one of his posts.

Comment: *"Why cant he just be a man, admit he is wrong and apologize for answering before he knew what he was talking about"* is not a question. It is a rant, disguised as a question. You should edit this — rants are not welcomed here, since RPG.SE Meta serves another purpose.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I think also that due to the gold badge privilege on dupes, it was a one person close as dupe.

Answer (score 19):

Stack Exchange sites are moderated by the entire community of users, who [unlock moderation privileges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) through contributions to the site. Some users also get elected by the community to become [diamond moderators](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) which is like a glorified janitor position.

Here on meta is where we the community members moderate each others' activity where necessary (including the diamond moderators being moderated). “We” here includes you.

> I am deleted by the moderator who posted the false answer.

Only one of your answers ([10k link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127283/1204)) has been removed by community members. One of the three users who removed it had a competing answer, which is usually an appearance of conflict of interest people should avoid. However, it was removed [in its initial revision](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/127283/1) for being very low quality and having no citation—it appeared to mainly just be calling out others as being wrong, but without providing a substantial case of its own. The comment you left on that answer (also since removed) did not help your case here.

The more recent version of your answer is a major improvement, and if it were in that state from the beginning it would not have been removed. The rant was removed by a fellow community member, and this was correct to do as well because answers are for answering the question directly. The space for observations about the community is here on meta.

As for who's right and wrong, we leave that to community votes and discourse to determine.

P.S.: Please note many of your peers on the site will not be male.

Comment: [Some of his peers on this site may not even be human](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f8/Internet_dog.jpg/220px-Internet_dog.jpg) ... please pardon me while I use my back foot to scratch behind my ears

Answer (score 8):

This site does not allow for duplicate questions.  I note that you appear to have asked or answered this exact question several times on two accounts. You can't ask the same question multiple times, even if you disagree with the answer, without that question being closed as a duplicate.

The [standard way](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6757/what-should-be-done-when-there-is-an-incorrect-common-answer-that-keeps-getting?rq=1) to correct an answer you believe to be incorrect is to place your own answer to the existing question. This will not always work well since the existing accepted answer usually has a vote lead, but it's possible (even [encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon)) for the asker to change the accepted answer to a new one if it's more correct.

The [deleted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127283/40971) of which you speak appears to have been nominated for deletion (including by Oblivious Sage, who has the accepted answer) due to your use of a rude and argumentative sentence:

> There is no passage limiting DR to one damage type per attack. **If you downvote without quoting such a rule you are promoting ignorance.** Rule is written as intended. ANY time damage of resisted type is taken, reduce damage.

Personally, I prefer mech's approach of simply removing that sentence, but if I had to guess the moderators' reason for deletion, it's that you appear to be using the site to force through your own reading of the rules rather than the site's intended purpose of asking for and providing answers.

I do not know why your answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127430/38502) was downvoted twice. It's good form, when downvoting an answer, to explain in a comment. It appears that this was not done <s>(or, if it was, moderators deleted the comments, which often happens)</s>. Your second answer was essentially a comment, and was deleted as it is not an answer to the question. The answer box is only for answers to the question.

To answer your literal question, it is most likely that the other user will not admit that they are wrong because they do not believe that they are wrong. You yourself appear to be in the same position. The case appears to be arguing over an ambigious rule, which is common in D&D and difficult to answer.

I recommend moving to D&D 5th edition and leaving this awkward edge case behind. Your miniatures will still work and you will be able to receive official rules answers on issues like this by asking Jeremy Crawford and Mike Mearls on Twitter.

---

Addendum: The user's entire post history on two accounts, which appears to be entirely arguing over this point:

- [How do vulnerabilities combine, when taking multiple types of damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/25649/40971) answered May 19 '13 at 3:20
- [How does Resist work against 1 attack that deals 2 separate damage types? [duplicate]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25650/40971) asked May 19 '13 at 3:26
- [How does Resist work against 1 attack that deals 2 separate damage types? [duplicate]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/25655/40971) answered May 19 '13 at 4:51 (accepted self-answer)
- [How does resist all apply to an attack that deals two types of (non-combined) damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127283/40971) answered two days ago
- [Damage resistance vs added damage by the RAW [duplicate]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127430/40971) asked 2 hours ago
- [Damage resistance vs added damage by the RAW [duplicate]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127432/40971) answered 2 hours ago (self-answer)
- [Damage resistance vs added damage by the RAW [duplicate]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127433/40971) answered 2 hours ago (deleted)

Comment: Related: [why is an answer being dowvnoted without comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6572/23970) In short, it's not *always* encouraged--or even good--to leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: On that answer only one comment was removed and it was from the OP.  Nobody has left feedback on downvoting it.

Comment: "It appears that[...]some moderators consider you to be acting in bad faith, and will downvote your attempts even if the individual answer is reasonable." Why do you say this? Do you have any evidence? If so, this would probably be a concerning move right?

Comment: I misspoke. I meant to say that _users_ may have downvoted the answer for acting in bad faith. Additionally, I cannot see any edit history on [the answer in question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127432/40971), so I had assumed the user was downvoted either for the question or for their past performance (i.e. the fact that they're asking this duplicate question yet again), rather than the answer itself, which is reasonably written. I have removed this erroneous suggestion from my answer. Please give me my upvotes back good sirs

Comment: I agree with the post history assessment you've made. Commentary on one of Chaz II's revisions suggesting their first question is five years ago, plus the same position expressed in the 2013 and 2018 answers, suggests this is a continuation of the same user. That explains SevenSidedDie's comment on the removed post from 2 days ago.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard Thanks for clarifying. That might be a reasonable assessment, too. When a user appears to be acting in bad faith (such as suggesting at each juncture that anyone disagreeing with them is wrong or ignorant, which has been edited out of each individual post from this account) it makes them into a downvote magnet: it's the community response of “no, this isn't welcome here.” In and of itself, in the present state, these posts would probably be OK, but the behaviour that's attached to them is a problem.

Answer (score 7):

From what I gather from comments on your question, and its edit history, ***you've been acting in bad faith.***

I highly recommend taking the [Tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). You may need to get oriented with how the different aspects of the site (questions, answers, comments, Meta, etc.) function.

Stack Exchange does not work like a forum. It is at its core a Q&A. Everybody here wants to help you find the answer you're looking for, but you have to help us do that. Please don't assume that anyone here is acting towards you or your question in bad faith; with malice or ill intent.

Comments and edits are for clarification. We are not inherently the owners of the posts we make, but the original querrent has the ability to currate an answer that was useful to them. If an answer isn't useful to you, that's okay; Just wait until another user submits another answer. There's no need to act with hostility towards an answer you do not find helpful.

If you have any questions please check out the links above and, when you have enough reputation, members in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com) are always more than happy to help.

***Note: I am not a moderator, and also did not witness the entire event. I am assuming by comments there are deleted answers and comments that I cannot see.***